# How to change column names in shell/bash?

Tags: shell

This question may be too simple for most of you, but I really don't want to do it manually. So, suppose I have a file in terminal such like this:

```
[dz2t@edison-s GWAS]$ head $PHENO
GWASID  CHILDID VSTNUM  GENDER  GA
1001    1001    11  Female  -9
1002    1002    11  Male    -9
1003    1003    11  male    -9
1004    1004    11  male    -9
1005    1005    11  Female  -9
1006    1006    11  Female  -9
```

How to change the names of first two columns from "GWASID" and "CHILDID" to "FID" and "IID". And the others remain unchanged?

Comment: Looks like question for `SuperUser.com`.

Comment: See [`sed`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sed -e '1s/GWASID/FID/' -e '1s/CHILDID/IID/' YourFile
```

That says, on line 1 only, substitute GWASID with FID and CHILDID with IID. If you want it to overwrite the file, you need to add the `-i` flag after the word `sed` for in-place editing.

Comment: so if I have 5 columns then I can just keep on adding  '-e' and '1s' followed by the column names , I suppose.  What did you mean by overwrite -i ?

Comment: @AdityaVerma Yes, `1s/.../.../` just means *"substitute on line 1"*.

Comment: @AdityaVerma If you want to change a file, without explicitly creating an intermediate file, use `sed -i ...`.