# Update csv headers in R without re-writing entire file

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to change the column names of a large csv file, and leave the rest as is. Can I do this without re-writing the entire file? My current code is slow:

```
library(data.table)
da = fread(file)
setnames(da, names(da), tolower(names(da)))
write.csv(da, file, row.names = F)
```

Comment: You can do this with `sed`.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264243/how-to-change-column-names-in-shell-bash

Comment: AFAIK R must read the file first in order to modify it. You could try gawk if you on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `sed` this will be very easy. Here is a sample file:

```
A,B,C
Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,3
```

You want to convert `A, B, C` to `a, b, c`. You can do this with:

```
 sed -e '1s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' test.csv > test-lower.csv
```

The contents of `test-lower.csv` is then:

```
a,b,c
Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,3
```